# How do i avoid polluting global namespace with this function?

Tags: javascript, loops, namespaces, prompt

i'm fiddling around trying to create a function that loops untill a matching answer is given, is there a better way to do this? I realize i'm polluting global namespace setting "loopBoolean = false/true"!

```
function userPrompt() {
    var loopBoolean = true;
    while(loopBoolean){
        var userChoice = prompt("type something").toLowerCase();
        if(userChoice === "gogo"){
            alert("good answer!");
            loopBoolean = false;
        }
        else{
            loopBoolean = true;
        }
    }
}
userPrompt();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not polluting global namespace by declaring variable `var loopBoolean` insdie your function.

The problem would be if you didn't use `var` keyword.

A better way to rewrite would be:

```
 while(prompt("type something").toLowerCase() != "gogo"){    
   // do sth if you need
 }
 alert("good answer!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are so bothered as `loopBoolean` is just a function scope variable, but you can use `break;` to end the loop instead, which makes the code much shorter and more readable...

```
function userPrompt() {
    while(true){
        var userChoice = prompt("type something").toLowerCase();
        if(userChoice === "gogo"){
            alert("good answer!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
userPrompt();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sakkL/)